# Using Weather Underground API with Weather-Icons over CDN

Tags: css, cdn, weather-api

Hello I'm trying to use https://erikflowers.github.io/weather-icons/ with the weather underground api via the API mapping as detailed here http://erikflowers.github.io/weather-icons/api-list.html but it's not able to pull the appropriate icons over cdn which I got here https://cdnjs.com/libraries/weather-icons/2.0.10 Unfortunately I have to use CDN on codepen.io anyone have experience with using WU api mappings with the weather-icons cdn?

To simplify if I wanted to correctly call this api mapping I would do so like this:

```
<i class="wi-wu-snow snow"></i>
```

correct?

Comment: Could you post your pen as it stands?

Comment: https://codepen.io/inkuplex/pen/QKaaWQ?editors=1111 for the record it will work if I do it without api mapping such as <i class="wi wi-night-sleet"></i>

Comment: Why do you have to map `chancerain` to `wi-wu-chancerain rain`? Why not map it to the css class you know is in the CDN's css? Something like `wi-rain`?

Comment: Ex. https://codepen.io/cam5/pen/QKBBBo?editors=1111

Comment: I assumed that is what this page is for http://erikflowers.github.io/weather-icons/api-list.html

Comment: Hm! When I inspect with devtools, it looks as if the css rule's applied. Maybe an issue w/ the SVG font?

Comment: Can you explain this last comment a little bit more?

Comment: Looks like you've fixed it! What did you do different?

Comment: No, it's still broken, it's just displaying the icon I told it to initially load with the DOM.

Comment: I found this https://github.com/erikflowers/weather-icons/issues/164 so I just said 'screw it' and ended up hard coding the mappings after all.

Comment: Ah well, glad you found an answer. You should "answer" this question, with that insight, so it's more visible to anyone in the future who hits the same wall!

Answer (score 0):

Look at this [link](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/weather-icons) . You can include those cdn link files, especially weather-icons.min.css file like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/weather-icons/2.0.9/css/weather-icons.min.css">
```

So later use erikflowers weather icons in this way:

```
<i class="wi wi-night-sleet"></i>
```

Hope it will work in your codepen.